# How to compare two text files for the same exact text using BASH Script?

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say I have two text files that I need to extract data out of. The text of the two files is as follows:

**File1.txt**

```
ami-1234567
ami-1234567654
ami-23456
```

**File-2.txt**

```
ami-1234567654
ami-23456
ami-2345678965
```

I want all the data of file2.txt which looks same from file1.txt.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _the data_ and by _looks same_. Do you mean all lines from the second file which also occur in the first file, i.e. the common lines in both file (irrespective of order)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `join`?

```bash
join -o 0 File1.txt File2.txt
```

```
ami-1234567654
ami-23456
```

**remark:** For `join` to work correctly, it needs your files to be sorted, which seems to be the case with your sample.

Comment: No data is not sorted in my case

Comment: one could sort at the same time via: `join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)`

Answer (score 1):

This is litteratly my first comment so I hope it works,

but you can try using diff:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option:

```
$ comm -1 -2  <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

The options specify that "unique" limes from first file (`-1`) and second file (`-2`) should be omitted.

This is basically the same as

```
$ join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Note that the sorting in both examples happens without creating an intermediate temp file, if you don't want to bother creating one.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know if I proper understand You:

but You can Try sort this files (after extract):

```
 sort file1 > file1.sorted
 sort file2 > file2.sorted
```